# Will Google + API shutdown affect APIs using "userinfo.email" scope which has "plus.me" dependency

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-plus, userinfo

We are getting user's email, display name and user image by accessing https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me API with **plus.me** scope.

Because of the Google+ API shutdown, we are planning to use https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo API as we already have the **userinfo.email** scope authenticated and the API returns our necessary user details (email, name and picture).

Just found out that **userinfo.email** scope has "plus.me" dependancy. Will this too be affected by the shutdown or is it only for projects directly requesting plus.me scope?

Also, will the https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo API still return user's email, name and user picture, even after Google+ shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

As long as **you** are no longer directly using any of the plus scopes or endpoints, you will be fine. Google does some mapping of the userinfo scopes into plus scopes internally, but these will be changed as part of the shutdown behind the scenes.

The https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo API endpoint will continue to work exactly as it does today, although keep in mind that this endpoint is being maintained for backwards compatibility (and has been for many years) and there are [newer versions](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtaininguserprofileinformation) of this endpoint and how to get userinfo.